# Disable vueform/slider when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 3 vueform/sliders using range inputs and also 3 checkboxes representing each. What I want is to have range disabled when no checkbox is checked. I tried taking the `v-model value` of the checkbox and showing it as range `disabled` but it didn't work because this time it can remove any checkbox disable event.I am attaching ss for better understanding.What actually i want like below. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Template

```
<div class="flex justify-between mb-16 items-center">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="wood"
    value="wood"
    v-model="checkedFilter"
    @change="onCheckbox($event)"
  />
  <label for="wood" class="ml-1 text-white">Wood</label>
  <Range
    v-model="wood"
    :min="0"
    :max="200"
    class="ml-20 w-[300%]"
    @change="woodSliderChanged"
  />
</div>
<div class="flex justify-between mb-16 items-center">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="food"
    value="food"
    v-model="checkedFilter"
    @change="onCheckbox($event)"
  />
  <label for="food" class="ml-1 text-white">Food</label>
  <Range
    v-model="food"
    :min="0"
    :max="200"
    class="ml-20 w-[300%]"
    @change="foodSliderChanged"
  />
</div>
<div class="flex justify-between mb-16 items-center">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="gold"
    value="gold"
    v-model="checkedFilter"
    @change="onCheckbox($event)"
  />
  <label for="gold" class="ml-1 text-white">Gold</label>
  <Range
    v-model="gold"
    :min="0"
    :max="200"
    class="ml-20 w-[300%]"
    @change="goldSliderChanged"
  />
</div>
```

Script

```
methods: {
    onCheckbox(event) {
      const { value } = event.target;
      if (this.checkedFilter.includes(value)) {
        this.costs.push({
          name:
            event.target.value[0].toUpperCase() +
            event.target.value.substring(1),
          value: this[value],
        });
      } else {
        this.costs = this.costs.filter(
          (cost) => cost.name.toLowerCase() !== value
        );
      }
      this.setCostFilter(this.costs);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by adding the `:disabled` attribute in the range element. As you have a custom `Range` component, You can pass checkbox value as a prop and then use it in the child/custom component.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('range', {
  data() {
    return {
        value: 50
    }
  },
  props: ['checkboxvalue'],
  template: '<input :disabled="!checkboxvalue" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" v-model="value"/>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedValue: null
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" id="gold" v-model="checkedValue"/>
  <label for="gold">Gold</label>
  <Range :checkboxvalue="checkedValue"></Range>
</div>
```